# Apache 2.4 - Check if authentification is valid by checking against another webserver

Tags: apache, authentication, basic-authentication, apache2.4

I have a webserver which hosts an application front end and another webserver hosting data.
The webserver does not store any data, all data is stored in a database (access via rest API). User credentials are also stored in the database.
Database webserver cannot be changed.
There is no ldap server or similar available.

For database webserver, basic authentication is used (every user has a unique login).

I would like to use Apache (2.4) basic authentication to authenticate users on the front-end webserver.

Is there a way to forward user credentials from front-end webserver and check against database webserver if credentials are valid?

```
User                 --- credentials -->   front-end webserver
front-end webserver  --- credentials -->   database webserver
front-end webserver  <-- 200 OK      ---   database webserver
User                 <-- 200 OK      ---   front-end webserver
```

Answer (score 0):

I used external auth and wrote my own small python script that (using requests) checks if user is allowed on database webserver.